# Sprite stretches when displayed with SpriteBatch.Draw XNA Framework

Tags: c#, xna

When using XNA Framework `spriteBatch.Draw()` the sprite appears stretched despite having seemingly same scale on both axes. From what I can see the sprite should be located 64 units from the left and should be pressed against the top of the window, but should be a square, rather than a rectangle. The texture is a simple 8x8 square.

Code:

```
spriteBatch.Draw(Content.Load<Texture2D>("enemies/blob/blob_walk0"), new Rectangle(64, 0, 128, 64), Color.White);
```

Sorry if this question isn't up to standard, I'm new to stackoverflow and don't really know what I'm doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`new Rectangle()` uses a method where you've to define the following in pixels: 
`(x, y, width, height)`.

In your case, the width is 128 pixels, while the height is 64 pixels. So it's width will stretch twice as much.

Replacing the `128` with `64` makes the width equall to the height, and will result in a square.